# In the struct dirent can file names have nonstandard characters?

Tags: c++, character-encoding

In the `struct dirent` can the member `d_name` have characters that are unicode but not ascii? I tested and it works with 'é' but I'm not sure if that's because 'é' is in ascii. What type is `d_name`, if it's `char` then I'm hooped but if it's `wchar_t` I'm saved.

Comment: I don't know about yours, but my `dirent` structure has `char d_name[FILENAME_MAX];`. To find yours specifically, just open up your `dirent.h` and look.

Comment: 'é' is not in ASCII. `d_name` probably contains the name encoded per the current locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Open Group Base Specifications state that `struct dirent` shall have the following member of unspecified size:

```
char d_name[];
```

In conforming implementations it is of type `char[]` but that doesn't necessarily mean that it can't store Unicode characters; the specification does not require the support of multiple character sets (or characters beyond the portable character set) but it doesn't forbid it either (`'é'` by the way, is not in ASCII).

In practice, the supported character set depends on your locale. In C terms, the string in `d_name` is stored as "multi byte" characters.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your platform and file system. For example the HFS+ file system stores filenames internally using UTF-16 and exposes them as UTF-8 so I think the `char` array in dirent should contain UTF-8 strings (regardless of your locale).

NTFS stores filenames in UTF-16 as well but what they are exposed as depends on the platform. Windows converts between the system locale and UTF-16. Another platform may convert between UTF-16 and UTF-8. Another platform may convert between UTF-16 and the immediate environment's locale.

Other file systems simply store and expose filenames as byte array and so dirent will contain whatever data was originally stored. This will usually be a string in the locale encoding, but there's no guarantee.