# switch statement matching non-ascii characters

Tags: c++, character-encoding

I have accented characters in my source code and have tried replacing them with the unicode equivalent. The program compiles and works properly if I use the actual non-ascii character but I'm concerned this may impact portability. When I try using the unicode equivalent I get *warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type* or *warning: character constant too long for its type* and the case is never matched when I run the program.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ent->d_namlen; i++)
{
    switch(ent->d_name[i])
    {
        case 'á' : //0x00E1
        ...
    }
 }
```

ent is `struct dirent *ent` that gets passed from a calling function.

In place of `case 'á' :` I've tried `case '0x00E1' :`, `case L 'u00E1 :`, `case \U000000E9 :` and `case '\u00E1' :` I've tried all without single quotes in which case it won't compile (e.g. says that \u00E1 was not declared in this scope).

Comment: What's the type of the variable you're switching on?

Comment: @Celeritas what do you think `sizeof (char)` is on your system? ;-)

Comment: @Dave [`dirent.d_name`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/dirent.h.html) is `char[]`

Comment: So it's not doable with dirent.d_name[]? I asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011510/in-the-struct-dirent-can-file-names-have-nonstandard-characters) and I thought I could.

Comment: Your unicode character is encoded as a multibyte value (00E1 is two bytes). You're presumably switching on a the first byte of that... the 0. You could try a case for 0, then check if d_name[i + 1] is E1.  Or, write some code to dump out the numeric values in d_name so you can see the encoding on a byte-by-byte level and use that to guide your detection of that character.

Comment: @TonyDelroy I don't think d_name[i+1] would work, I think that would be the next character in the array. What dumping code did you have in mind?

Comment: @TonyDelroy note that you are making a large assumption on the character encoding and locale there ;-)

Comment: @Celeritas do you know what a *multi-byte strings* are?

Comment: @Celeritas: the `char` type in C++ is (overwhelmingly often) an 8-bit value... it can hold an ASCII character, but not a unicode character.  Unicode characters will be encoded in multiple `char` values according to some specific encoding - that you're expecting 00E1 suggests one `00` char and one `E1` char, but as veer points out that's making the assumption that what you're trying to check for actually matches the encoding standard in use.

Comment: Display the values of the characters in d_name to see what you should be looking for. To do that, use `printf("%d", d_name[whatever])` or `std::cout << (int)d_name[whatever]`.

Comment: @veer you mean the multi-byte character sets as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2995/The-Complete-Guide-to-C-Strings-Part-I-Win32-Chara)?

Comment: @Celeritas well I would probably not read something advertised as being Win32 specific... but you can read more [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte).

Comment: Ok I see the problem with the multi-byte encoding. @PeteBecker I did what you said and numbers range from 70 to 196, though this will vary depending on input.

Comment: @Celeritas if you convert to a *wide-character string*, then what you're doing is more readily possible, so long as you specify the correct locale and what not.

Comment: @veer How can I convert it to a wchar_t without rewriting the dirent.h library?

Comment: @Celeritas maybe [`mbstowcs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbstowcs)? :-)

Comment: I think you are all missing the point. OP wants to do some kind of text processing not knowing the first thing about character encoding. All this detour about `wchar_t` (which may also be variable-length, so it doesn't solve anything by itself) doesn't help with the fact that the text input has to be in a known encoding for any kind of text processing to make sense. That's why portability libraries try to normalize on an encoding. GLib for example uses utf-8 unless otherwise specified (providing the proper encoding functions).

Comment: If you ask questions about compiler errors, it would help a lot if you posted the actual errors together with the question. Please edit your question to add the errors, and please do a verbatim copy-paste without editing or filtering the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`á` is a non-ASCII character and is being represented as multiple bytes in either your source code, the `struct dirent`, or both.

If you turn on `-Wmultichar` you will probably get the warning

```
warning: multi-character character constant
```

indicating that the character constant `'á'` consists of more than one byte, in which case it's probably in UTF-8, but check (e.g. using `file`).  You'll also need to find out the encoding of the `dirent` entries.

In order to match non-ASCII characters in a string you need to:

- make sure that the string and the character are represented in the same encoding, and either

  - use a fixed-length encoding (i.e. UCS-4) and a type sufficiently wide to store each codepoint (e.g. `int`), or
  - use a restartable variable-length encoding (i.e. UTF-8) and use substring matching.

Look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8 for an example of how to do the conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I think converting the switch expression to unsigned type will do the trick.

```
switch((unsigned char)ent->d_name[i])
{
...
}
```